# Way to record / capture HDMI and composite signals?

Tags: hdmi, video-capture

I'd like to record both HDMI and composite signals, in that it records the audio and video to a device for retrieval later without any computer connection required.

Is there any available hardware that can record and capture 1080p HDMI and composite signals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking this question led to using the search terms of "***offline hdmi capture***", where a device from [agptek](https://shop.category5.tv/?product=1080p-30-fps-hdmi-component-video-capture-to-usb-without-computer) was found (video: 2017, LinuxTechShow, "[Record Your Gameplay Without A Computer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsPGwrtpYT8)") and is as shown below:

[image: Picture of offline USB HDMI/composite capture device]